# svg support for html5 site running on Windows Azure websites

Tags: html, svg, azure-web-app-service

Experimenting with Google Polymer - posted the Tutorial code to an Azure website (polymer.azurewebsites.net) - but the svg images won't render (404 per console). I'm assuming this is related to the solutions which modify web.config to provide the mimeType for svg - but web.config is only relevant to asp.net websites, not HTML5. Is there any way to implement svg handling on a non-asp.net site?

Comment: The problem is fixed. I had created a web.config which reflected the content that Ranjith's link pointed to already, but it broke the site. I finally loaded the whole thing into WebMatrix and ran it - I got a more verbose error message from IIS which pointed to a punctuation error in the web.config. Once I got that fixed, the site started working and showing the svg images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

web.config is not just related to asp.net sites - its IIS site/application configuration. Example - http://madskristensen.net/post/prepare-webconfig-for-html5-and-css3